# Importing multiple CSV into one DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I tried many answers but none of them working for me:

For example this: [Import multiple CSV files into pandas and concatenate into one DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906474/import-multiple-csv-files-into-pandas-and-concatenate-into-one-dataframe)

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

path = r'C:\DRO\DCL_rawdata_files' # use your path
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path , "/*.csv"))

li = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

I have only 2 csv files:

1.csv:

```
1,1
2,1
3,1
4,1
5,1
```

2.csv:

```
6,1
7,1
8,1
9,1
```

To be fair, this is my routine for merging:

```
files = glob.glob("data/*.csv")
df = []
for f in files:
    csv = pd.read_csv(f, index_col=None, header=0)
    df.append(csv)
df = pd.concat(df, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
df.to_csv("all.csv")
print(df);
```

This is the output (print(df)):

```
   1  1.1    6
0  2  1.0  NaN
1  3  1.0  NaN
2  4  1.0  NaN
3  5  1.0  NaN
4  1  NaN  7.0
5  1  NaN  8.0
6  1  NaN  9.0
```

And this is the "all.csv":

```
,1,1.1,6
0,2,1.0,
1,3,1.0,
2,4,1.0,
3,5,1.0,
4,1,,7.0
5,1,,8.0
6,1,,9.0
```

Whereas I would need all.csv to be:

```
1,1
2,1
3,1
4,1
5,1
6,1
7,1
8,1
9,1
```

I'm using Python3.9 with PyCharm 2022.3.1.

Why is my all.csv look like that, and how can I simply read multiple csv into one dataframe for further processing?

Comment: You should read csv with `header=None` option. Also, if your target is the final `all.csv`, you'd be better off reading the csv as text files and concatenate them.

Comment: My target is DataFrame, just I wanted to write it out, for testing the result.

Comment: and I have "header=0", isn't it enough?

Comment: No, `header=0` means to take the first row as column names, and the result is what you see. `header=None` means no column names. It should give you the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You have to swap `header` and `index_col` values:

```
data = []
for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=0, header=None)
    data.append(df)
df = pd.concat(data, axis=0)
df.to_csv('all.csv', header=False)
```

Output `all.csv`:

```
1,1
2,1
3,1
4,1
5,1
6,1
7,1
8,1
9,1
```

Comment: For me if I don't add `index=None` into "to_csv", I got an extra line at the top with "0 1".

Comment: This is the header, you have to use `header=False` to avoid this leading row.

Comment: So I really should go with `pd.read_csv(f, index_col=None, header=None)` AND `df.to_csv('all.csv', header=False, index=None)`

Comment: `header=False` for me eliminates the row headers, not the column headers

Comment: Are you sure you are not confusing the two concepts: index (= the number of rows) and columns (= the number of columns)?

Answer (score 0):

I have been successfully using this code to append several Excel files into one dataframe; it also forces certain columns to be string datatypes, which can be changed, of course:

```
fmask = 'C:/Users/USER/FILEPATH/*.xlsx'

# lst of column names which needs to be string
lst_str_cols = ['ItemID', 'StoreID']
# use dictionary comprehension to make dict of dtypes
dict_dtypes = {x : 'str'  for x in lst_str_cols}

dfs = []
for f in glob.glob(fmask):
    df = pd.read_excel(f, dtype=dict_dtypes)
    dfs.append(df)

# concatenated
dfConcatenate = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Instead of Excel you can change it to CSV.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('csvfile1.csv', header=None)
df1 = pd.read_csv('csvfile2.csv', header=None)

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row[0], row[1])
```